# how to fix this category select method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I'm just trying to make category for my movie blog and its working fine, but the editing category must be selected right.
So I did something like this:

```
//fetching all categories
@foreach($categories as $category)

  //start option
  <option 

  //fetching current movie categories
  @foreach($movie->categories as $cat)

    //matching is this category match with
    @if($category->name === $cat->name)

    //if match selected method works
    selected="selected" 

    @endif

  @endforeach

  >{{ $category->name }}

  </option>
@endforeach
```

and its working fine but i thinks its a wrong way
can u suggest me good way to do this
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:
`@if(in_array( $category->name ,$movie->categories->pluck('name')) 
   {{'selected' }} 
@endif`

if give you a `type arg2 must be an array error`. add a `toArray()` after the pluck methods.

Comment: @if( $movie->categories->contains('name', $category->name )) selected="selected" @endif

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I do it.

```
    <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ isset($gallery) && $category->id == $gallery->category_id?'selected':''}}>{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

You can use ternary operator instead of using `if()`.

If you have many to many relationship then you can try

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}"  {{$movie->categories->contains('name', $category->name )?'selected':'' @endif >{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i found laravel style and its optimized version working fine
@if( $movie->categories->contains('name', $category->name ))

selected="selected" 

@endif

Comment: lols I was just writing this i found you have many to many relationship

Comment: Can you copy paste my ans that I can give you green tick